# Document Picker in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, file-upload

Scenario: Say end-user got a attachment in mail app in ios. And user wants to upload this file in my app.

In React native is there any good working component? I want to use it to create facility where my user can upload files( not images).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/aroth/react-native-uploader

Comment: Yes this is true but here we have to give link in this component. So need to show document picker which is not like that. So maybe this is helpful:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker

Comment: @JAINESHDOSHI , Thanks for the info. I used document picker to select file.

IshitaSinha, thanks for the link. it is good component which i missed it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @jaineshdoshi, component hosted at www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker can be used as document picker..

ps: since ios 11 has file app, this solution might work differently on older ios version